# Android Studio Multiple GridLayouts Programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I am working on a project in Android Studio, where I have a number of tabbed fragments containing master detail views that present a list in the master and a single gridlayout in the detail, and these are simply laid out in the xml layouts and work perfectly. For the final tab detail view, I need to be able to present multiple separate horizontally scrolling single row and dynamic column count gridlayouts, or gridviews, with a TextView header for each, and it must be done programmatically as they are likely to differ depending on the master view list selection. This is so easy on iOS using collection views, but there are no examples that I can find for Android that do the same, and every thing I have tried results in a single gridlayout, with no TextView header. Can anyone provide a simple example (with maybe three grids) of how this might be done?

Comment: Your description is confusing me. Can you add a screenshot of what you want and/or the code you have up to now?

Comment: if you want help, you should write the generic example beforehand...

Comment: Thank you so much for even responding @Soana, I worked it out for myself, and below is the fairly simple answer. I just hope it helps others so that they don't have the same issues I did in getting any help on here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView svv = new ScrollView(this);
    svv.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int colcount = 20;
    int rowcount = 1;
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;
    GridLayout grd;
    GridLayout.LayoutParams gllop;
    HorizontalScrollView svh;

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("TextView " + i);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
    linLayout.addView(tv);
    grd = new GridLayout(this);
    grd.setColumnCount(colcount);
    grd.setRowCount(rowcount);
    grd.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            gllop = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0), GridLayout.spec(j));
            btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button " + i +"."+j);
            grd.addView(btn, gllop);
        }
        svh = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        svh.addView(grd);
        linLayout.addView(svh);
    }
    svv.addView(linLayout);
    setContentView(svv, linLayoutParam);

}
```